# Querying Google Play Music database in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to query for the playlists created by "Google Play Music" app but haven't been able to do so. I created a playlist using locally stored content. I used the following code to query:

```
Cursor c = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                       new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID,
                                                     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME
                                                    }, null, null, null);
```

This works fine for Winamp but not for Google Play Music. In fact, Winamp doesn't display the playlists created with Google Play Music. However, Google Play Music displays the playlists created with Winamp. My guess is that Google Play Music is using its own database to store the playlists where as other players use Content Provider with uri MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to store their playlists. Is there a way to get playlists created with Google Play Music?

Answer (score 14):

I know this thread is old, but I have been grappling with this problem too.

Google Play Music exposes its playlists at this non-standard Content URI

```
// list all playlists with their ID and Name
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    "content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists", 
    new String[] {"_id", "playlist_name" }, 
    null, null, null);
```

The Google Play Music content provider uses the following column names

- isAllLocal
- playlist_owner_name
- hasLocal
- hasRemote
- hasAny
- KeepOnId
- playlist_art_url
- playlist_share_token
- _id
- _count
- playlist_owner_profile_photo_url
- keeponSongCount
- playlist_description
- playlist_type
- playlist_id
- keeponDownloadedSongCount
- playlist_name

I would have never figured this out without this really helpful app [Content Provider Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jensdriller.contentproviderhelper)

Comment: Could you please post the column names of a track object? I just installed the Content Provider Helper, but "content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists" is not listed there.

Comment: @Chrizzor, if you pass null for the second argument of the query (instead of passing a list of columns), the result will contain all columns. Then you can inspect the value of the cursor (it has a property mCursor with a property mColumns) to see all the column names. I'd list them here, but there are 47 of them!

Comment: It returns only one record ie, the playlist which was last created. Doesn't return all the records.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
Uri gMusicUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio");
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
            .query(gMusicUri,
                    proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanx user1411426, is thr similar way to retreive the album art for a particular song-id ?

Answer (score 0):

Î tried querying the ContenProvider like you can see it in Logcat when  you Start the google Music app:

getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists"), null, null, null, null);

but I got no result :-( maybe Im doing s.th. wrong, didnt work much with contentproviders before, or maybe the contentprovider is not public for other apps.

Comment: This actually worked for me with a minor change. Instead of using "null" projection, I used {MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID}.

I only need the IDs and names of playlists. So, this serves my need.