# Android/Qt Access Databases

Tags: java, android, qt, permissions

I need to access the file,

```
/data/data/com.google.android.music/databases/music.db
```

It's currently denied. I'm using Qt to target the Android platform. I think it's easier to just use Qt's methods to read the database than fiddle with the JNI/NDK.

I think it's the permissions: the default permissions, which aren't working out for me, are as follows-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using other application's private files is not allowed in Android. There is no permission to do that. You have to use the proper ContentResolver to access that data. And I suppose the only way is by using the public Java API through JNI glue code.

Read this for details about how to use that ContentResolver: [Querying Google Play Music database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669358/querying-google-play-music-database-in-android).

Comment: Hmm. I tried it. I had problems getting the Context of the application.

Comment: You mean a android.content.Context? Where do you need it? In your C/C++ implementation?

Comment: Yes. As far as JNI, I can get a function requiring the Context as an argument, which if I could pass would work. It worked on pure Java, but I can't pass the Context in, and I can't do it any other way. Which is why I tried to just pull the database manually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, anyway I don't see the problem with the Context. Just save it in a static variable in Java as soon as the application starts. The Java method you invoke from C++ then will take a reference to the Context from that static variable. You can save it from a subclass of the Application class or wherever you want. I've done it many times.